# MySQL, Java and Inserting into tables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public ResultSet runQuery(String cmd, String table, String[] keys, String[] values,          String[] whereKeys, String[] whereValues, int limitStart, int limitCount) throws    Exception
{
    PreparedStatement stmt;

    if(!(cmd.equals("INSERT") || cmd.equals("SELECT") || cmd.equals("UPDATE") || cmd.equals("DELETE")))
    {
        throw new Exception("CMD UNSUPPORTED! CMD must be INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE.");
    }

    String sql = "";
    if(cmd.equals("INSERT"))
    {
        //Build Insert statement
        sql += "INSERT INTO "+table+" (";

        for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            sql += ""+keys[i]+"";
            if(i!=keys.length-1)
                sql+=",";
        }

        sql += ") VALUES(";

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            sql += "'?'"; //This line seems to be causing trouble for me...
            if(i!=values.length-1)
                sql+=",";
        }

        sql += ")";

    }
```

Context: I am working on a class project, and was assigned the database team. I have very little experience with MySQL and was partnered up with someone that claims to have a ton of experience with MySQL and Java. This is the function he created for Insert, Select, Update and Delete. Every function I have created that uses one of these functions has had errors, and requires modification of this original runQuery function. The main thing I have been trying to work with is the "insert" command. I have to be able to create a User, Admin, or a Class (like a college class), and insert the appropriate information(names, userNames, passwords, tableID). I can create a user or admin without generating an error, but when I create a class, I get an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut2ha.jpg

```
public boolean createUser(String first, String last, String user, String pass)
{
    String[] keys = {"FName", "LName", "UName", "Password"};
    String[] vals = {first, last, user, pass};

    try
    {
        runQuery("INSERT", "Users", keys, vals, null, null, 0, 30);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}



public boolean createClass(int classID, String name, int adminID, String institution, String meetTimes)
{
    String[] keys = {"ClassID", "ClassName", "AdminID", "Institution", "MeetTimes"};
    String[] vals = {Integer.toString(classID), name, Integer.toString(adminID), institution, meetTimes};

    try
    {
        runQuery("INSERT", "Classes", keys, vals, null, null, 0, 30);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

TL;DR: I am having trouble inserting new 'classes' into a table, and think the error relates back to the runQuery function. I have omitted the rest of the runQuery function for now, as I don't think its necessary for this problem, but I can add it in its entirety of 241 lines. Based on what I am seeing online in regards to this situation, preparedStatements seem like a much easier way to input info, no?

Thanks for reading through this and your possible help!

Answer (score 0):

From the linked image to the stack trace it seems someone tries to execute a statement with arguments with ? place holders. The SQL engine complains that the argument for ClassID is '?'. It should be ? not '?' since numerical values do not need ''. Strange however is the fact that I can't spot any ClassID argument in the query.

Comment: I have the line where the ? marked as problematic, should the syntax be: sql += "?"; or sql += ?;

Comment: If the corresponding type is string aka VARCHAR or such it should be '?' if it's numeric its ?. Just think that when replacing your ? with the values from your variables it should result in a well defined SQL command.

Comment: So how does one handle different data types for input? I assume this is a common problem, with a rather simple solution...

Comment: No it isn't. There are calls in the JDBC API that allow you to identify column types and you may adapt your parameter accordingly but I would recommend to rethink the design. The whole thing smells a bit like an [Inner-Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) which almost always is a bad idea.  The runQuery method is supposed to be an inner service routine but does it realy do anything more then calling PreparedStatement.exec ? In an ideal case all SQL queries needed for your application are known beforehand and can be placed as static const strings or PreparedStatements.

Comment: Based on my "research", I am seeing the PreparedStatements used quite often for inserting, and it seems to be a much easier and efficient system for handling this stuff. I kinda figured redoing this would be the simplest solution. Thanks for your input, I truly appreciate it.